# Google Cloud Console Quotas You don't have permissions to perform the action on the selected resource

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am the admin of my organization and I visit https://console.cloud.google.com/ IAM & Admin and click on Quotas I get `You don't have permissions to perform the action on the selected resource.`. Why am I getting this. If I am the org admin and getting this error then who is able to view Quotas?
I am logged in using incognito window.

Answer (score 0):

You are not "owner" even you are "organization administrators".
Please assign yourself either primitive role like "owner" or "editor"
Or predefined role "Quota Viewer" and let me know.

Comment: And how can I do that? Google cloud platform console is a mess.

Comment: Please check the official documentation [Granting, changing, and revoking access to resources](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access)

Comment: Is this issue is resolved or still persists, Please check the official documentation [Granting](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access) [Revocking](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access)[Access to resources](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access)